# HOW TO RESOLVE NODE - SQL Server CONNECTION FAILURE

Tags: node.js, sql-server

I am building a NodeJS app and would like to use SQL Server for persistence storage. Before, I have never had problems connecting to MySQL Server but I am now getting the following error when attempting to connect to SQL Server:

> ConnectionError: Error: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]SQL Server Network Interfaces: Connection string is not valid [87].
> Error: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Login timeout expired
> Error: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.

Below is my config and connection using `mssql/msnodesqlv8` module.

```
const mssql = require('mssql/msnodesqlv8')

const dbConfig = 
    "server":"127.0.0.1",
    "user":"sa",
    "password":"PasswordHere",
    "database":"DBName_Here",
    "driver":"msnodesqlv8",
    "dialect":"mssql",
    "port":1433,
    "options":{
        "enableArithAort":true,
        "instanceName":"MSSQLSERVER"
    },
    "connectionTimeout":15000,
    "pool":{
        "max":100,
        "min":0,
        "idleTimeoutMillis":30000
    }
}

ValidateUser = async (data)=>{
        console.log(data)
       return new Promise(async (resolve, reject)=>{
           console.log(dbConfig)
           try{
                let pool = await mssql.connect(dbConfig)
                let results = await pool.request().query(`SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Username  = ${data.username} AND Password = ${data.password}`)
                results = results.recordSets
                console.log(results)
                if(results.length > 0){
                    resolve(results)
                }else{
                    reject('Wrong Username or Password!')
                }
           }catch(err){
               console.log(err)
               reject('DB Exception: Authentication failed!')
           }
       })
    }
```

I have attempted variations of the config including replacing the IP with my machine name `DESKTOP-GLPFSS\COMPUTERNAME` but to no avail. All relevant support will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use `port`, or use `instanceName`, not both. Prefer to use `port` when you know it. When you use `instanceName` then udp/1434 has to be accessible on the target machine so that the SQL Browser Service can be used to resolve the instance name to a port number, to which the client then attempts to establish a TCP connection.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the settings in SQL Server Configuration Manager are properly set:

Please follow below steps to verify it and try to configure it as per the attached image

1. Click the Windows key + R to open the Run window.
2. Type compmgmt.msc in the Open: box.
3. Click OK.
4. Expand Services and Applications.
5. Expand SQL Server Configuration Manager

[image]

Instead of "MSSQLSERVER" look for instance name which you provided at time of installation.

Comment: One more thing, please restart the sql server service after making above changes.